# Grails i18n From Database but Default Back To File

Tags: grails, internationalization

Following [this blog article](http://graemerocher.blogspot.com/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html) I enabled my application to load i18n messages from the database.  It works great.  However, I don't want to manage all messages in the database.  So I'd like to be able to say if I don't find the code in the database, then load it using the default mechanism.

Here is what I have:

```
class DatabaseMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {
  protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
    Message msg = Message.findByCodeAndLocale(code, locale)
    def format = null
    if (msg) {
      format = new MessageFormat(msg.text, msg.locale)
    }else{
      // What do I do here to grab it from the file
    }
    return format;
  }
}
```

I tried calling super.resolveCode(code, locale) but that resulted in compile errors.  And I'm having a hard time tracking down the implementation of AbstractMessageSource that Grails is using by default to look at the source.

UPDATE: Thanks to doelleri I now realize what I need to do is something like extending the  ResourceBundleMessageSource.  Unfortunately, there are several issues with this approach.  I have the following in my resources.groovy file:

```
messageSource(DatabaseMessageSource)
```

First of all, if I simply extend ResourceBundleMessageSource and override the resolveCode method, that method never gets called.  So in my else block, calling super.resolveCode is moot.

I then attempted to just implement my DatabaseMessageSource class with all the code from ResourceBundleMessageSource but I'm apparently missing something in resources.groovy because the default bundles aren't getting wired up.

So at this point, I'm still lost on what I need to do.  I want to first check the database.  If the code doesn't exist, revert to the same default behavior as ResourceBundleMessageSource.

Comment: Did you ever got this working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would propose to keep one bundle-message-source in a new bean and inject it into your `DatabaseMessageSource`.

**resources.groovy:**

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    messageSource(DatabaseMessageSource) {
        messageBundleMessageSource = ref("messageBundleMessageSource")
    }    
    messageBundleMessageSource(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource) {
        basenames = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    }
}
```

**DatabaseMessageSource.groovy:**

```
class DatabaseMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    def messageBundleMessageSource

    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
         Message msg = Message.findByCodeAndLocale(code, locale)
         def format
         if(msg) {
             format = new MessageFormat(msg.text, msg.locale)
         }
         else {
             format = messageBundleMessageSource.resolveCode(code, locale)
         }
         return format;
    }
}
```

This way, in fallback solution, the message will be read from the appropriate `messages_*.properties` file, by just requesting it from one resource bundle message source. Note that you should use the `PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource`, otherwise you could miss some important messages from your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You may extend ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource (the original grails message bundle, which does not seem to be final) instead and then apply this code:

```
class DatabaseMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {
  protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
    Message msg = Message.findByCodeAndLocale(code, locale)
    def format = null
    if (msg) {
      format = new MessageFormat(msg.text, msg.locale)
    }else{
      format = super.resolveCode(code,locale)
    }
    return format;
  }
}
```

You may also reconfigure your message resources in Resources.groovy:

```
 beans = {
    messageSource(com.mycompany.DatabaseMessageSource) {
        basename = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nope, using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource doesn't work either.  It doesn't even get into my DatabaseMessageSource class where I have break points set.  And the only messages getting rendered are the default  messages supplied in the message taglib usage.

Comment: I guess somehow the wiring in the resources.groovy is not good, ie not overriding the default messageSource configuration. Also check the configuration of resources.groovy, my original config was erroneous, ie use `beans {..}` and don't forget com.mycompany.... or whatever prefix you use

Answer (score 0):

resolveCode(code, locale) in AbstractMessageSource is an abstract method so you will not be able to call it. Try extending [ResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) or [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) instead.

Comment: Aha!  Thanks.  ResourceBundleMessageSource is probably what I need.  I'll test it out in the morning and report back.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: As it turns out, simply extending ResourceBundleMessageSource doesn't work.  The method resolveCode never gets called and if I try and implement it the exact same way it is coded in the actual class (I downloaded the source code) it doesn't get wired up with all its bundle info correctly based on what I am doing in the resources.groovy file.  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not Grails specific, we at Griffon created CompositeResourceBundle and DelegatingResourceBundle as parts of our own i18n plugin (source found at http://svn.codehaus.org/griffon/plugins/griffon-i18n/trunk/src/main/griffon/plugins/i18n/).

ExtendedResourceBundleMessageSource shows how these classes can be used.

Comment: Thanks aalmiray.  I really need to revert back to as default Spring / Grails as possible.  You're code looks like it is handling loading the bundles on their own.  I need Grails to load the bundles the way grails loads them.  I just need to add the ability to first look in the database for the message.  Maybe I'm just too tired right now to get it.  But I also think that the trick lies in how I define my bean in resources.groovy which will probably require a grails answer.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to use `Copycopter` (http://copycopter.com) to manage i18n keys content. It will allow your team to update keys on the fly easily, using a friendly interface, and you will be able to set the default as you wanted. This way no one will come to you when a key needs to be updated.

ThoughtBot, a strong web development consulting company is behind that product. It is solid.

Your code will look like this then:

```
mail :to => member.email,
     :subject => I18n.translate("member_mailer.reminder_to_sign_in.#{underscored_number_of_days}.subject",
                                :default => %{You have not signed in for #{humanized_number_of_days}})
```

The i18n keys are generated on the fly on copytcopter, the first time you use it. It is really easy to use.

Check it out, it is worth it.