# Grails i18n from property files backed up by a DB?

Tags: grails, internationalization

i am trying to get a situation where i can use i18n property files which are backed up with a database?

So for some standard stuff i would like to use the property files, but some fields must be editable by the end-user so i was planning to use i18n in the database for that. So a real combination would be great. If the i18n code cannot be found in the property files then do a lookup in the DB.

Any idea how i can tackle this? I have seen the post [Grails i18n From Database but Default Back To File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100312/grails-i18n-from-database-but-default-back-to-file)

But there is no real answer to the problem, any other suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: have a deeper look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100312/grails-i18n-from-database-but-default-back-to-file. there is blog referenced, which shows, how to retrieve messages from database. the stackoverflow message will show you, how to combine database and message files.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out, but the actual question has never been fully answered. At least there is no clue what the solution could be. :( I also checked this post.. 

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/i18n-Database-td4073132.html#a4115736

But again no real solution also.

Comment: Have you realized the reference to this blog? http://graemerocher.blogspot.com/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a new domain class into your project:

```
class Message {
    String code
    Locale locale
    String text
}
```

Add the following lines to your `resources.groovy`:

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    messageSource(DatabaseMessageSource) {
        messageBundleMessageSource = ref("messageBundleMessageSource")
    }    
    messageBundleMessageSource(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource) {
        basenames = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    }
}
```

And add the following class to your `src/groovy` folder:

```
class DatabaseMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    def messageBundleMessageSource

    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
         Message msg = messageBundleMessageSource.resolveCode(code, locale)
         def format
         if(msg) {
             format = new MessageFormat(msg.text, msg.locale)
         }
         else {
             format = Message.findByCodeAndLocale(code, locale)
         }
         return format;
    }
}
```

Now grails will try to resolve the message from the message bundle. If it is not available, it will look it up from database. You could add some error-handling, but this version works, if all messages are available at least in one place.

See http://graemerocher.blogspot.com/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html for some more details.

---

Some details on the changes done in `resources.groovy`:

In this file you can define injectable groovy classes, which can be included by just defining a variable having the same name as defined in the `resources.groovy`. E.g. in this file, there are `messageSource` and `messageBundleMessageSource`, which you can be include in any controller or service files. If this variable is defined, an instance of the class in the brackets is created.

In this case, we overwrite the general `messageSource` to use our custom implementation `DatabaseMessageSource`. So the I18n function `message` will now use our custom implementation.

Since our custom implementation requires to check the `message.properties`-files we keep the **original** message source in the second bean. By defining this instance in our custom implementation, we can still use the old implementation (and therefore looking up messages the usual way).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example code! For me it was a combination of things that i did not know. 

The configuration of the resources.groovy is still a little bit difficult. To fully understand, could you elaborate a bit more on what it is configured?

More specific..

           `messageBundleMessageSource(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource) {
    basenames = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    }`

Comment: I will post my implemented solution of your suggestion, could you please give the code a quick look and tell me if all seems fine. There where small errors i ran into when running your example. But maybe i missed something! Thanks!

Comment: I updated the response, so you have some more details to the changes in the `resources.groovy`.

Comment: Do you know a way in which to have a wildcard to the basenames property? We have multiple property files. It is no problem to type them all out, but it would be nice to have a wildcard. Do you know if this is available?

Comment: What exactly does this line mean? `messageBundleMessageSource = ref("messageBundleMessageSource")`

Comment: 1. its the same behaviour as the usual message source - as far as i know. 2.

Comment: `messageBundleMessageSource = ref("messageBundleMessageSource")` means, that the bean, which this line is contained in, has a property (`messageBundleMessageSource`), which is also defined in this `resources.groovy`. But since it is unknown (forward declaration) at this point, you need to use `ref(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I know what you mean by

> i18n property files which are backed up with a database

But if you simply mean that you want the message keys to be resolved using a database table (instead of a .properties file), then you can do this by writing your own implementation of the MessageSource interface

```
class DBMessageSource implements MessageSource {
  String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) {
   // IMPLEMENT ME
  }

  String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) {
   // IMPLEMENT ME    
  }

  String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
   // IMPLEMENT ME    
  }
}
```

Then simply replace the default implementation of the `messageSource` bean with your implementation by adding the following to `resources.groovy`

```
messageSource(DBMessageSource)
```

Comment: I am trying to combine both, so if a code cannot be found in the property files i want to look them up inside a db table. This to enable users to modify some specific fields if needed. So 95% of the fields will be in the property files and 5% in a db table.

Comment: OK, then you'll need an implementation of MessageSource that checks the property files first, then checks the database

Answer (score 0):

In followup of the answer of @crudolf i implemented the following method to achieve my goal.

```
class DatabaseMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {
    // the message bundle resource that holds all of the messages
    def messageBundleMessageSource

    // the default locale used when there is no correct results found
    // if a visitor (x) comes along with an unknown locale in the DB
    // then this locale will be used as fallback!
    Locale fallbackLocale = new Locale("nl", "NL")

    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
        // first try to find the message in the messagebundles
        MessageFormat messageFormat = messageBundleMessageSource.resolveCode(code, locale)

        if(!messageFormat) {
            // no message found so lets find one in the database
            def message = Message.findByCodeAndLocale(code, locale) ?: Message.findByCodeAndLocale(code, fallbackLocale)
            if (message) {
                // found one create a message format!
                messageFormat = new MessageFormat(message.text, message.locale)
            } else {
                // not found! create a standard message format
                messageFormat = new MessageFormat(code, locale)
            }
        }
        return messageFormat
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/goeh/grails-i18n-db and https://github.com/halfbaked/grails-localizations. Both offer also a gui to manage localizations.