# How to get the validation messages from the database instead of properties?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

**Background**

We are migrating a legacy database that have the labels of fields internacionalized in the database. We still use the `messages.properties` for some static resouces like css classes (names). The table looks like:

```
ITEMS
-------------------------------------------
code           number(3)      not null PK
language_code  number(3)      not null PK
label          varchar2(90)   not null
hint           varchar2(250)  not null
help           varchar2(4000)
label_client   varchar2(90)   not null
hint_client    varchar2(250)  not null
help_client    varchar2(4000)
```

For the html components we just look for the item in this table, setting his label (custom TagLib), and this works well. Note that we also give the opportunity to the client modify some label (the *_client fields).

**The Problem**

By default, Grails will try to look in messages.properties with the suffix `.label` to use in the validation error message. For example (`Person.name.label=name`):

```
Property name must not be blank.
```

If my item in the database have the label Name of Person, in validations this will be inconsistent as the label of the input differs.

We cannot synchronize the items with the .properties because the client can change them. So the solution is to, somehow, modify the Grails validation messages to return the content of the database.

Is this possible? How can I, just for validation messages, get from the database instead of properties?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297505/grails-i18n-from-property-files-backed-up-by-a-db

Comment: @tim_yates hmmm I pass through this topic but not remembered. Thanks! I will try that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog post](http://graemerocher.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html) suggests you can do it by implementing your own `messageSource` Spring bean and registering it in `resources.groovy`.  It dates from 2010 but still worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Ian. The question that tim pointed is a little more elaborated than the blog post but both are valid resources. I will have to customize them, associating the field of my domain class with the code (numeric in my database) but I think that this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Localization plugin! ;)

http://grails.org/plugin/localizations

From the plugin overview:

This plugin will pull i18n definitions from the database rather than from the standard properties files in the i18n folder.

It will do the following:

Create a domain class and corresponding table called Localization
Prepopulate the table with all the message properties it finds in the i18n folder
Ensure Grails writes i18n messages based on what it finds in the database rather than the 118n folder

In addtion the plugin also has these added features to help you:

A CRUD UI to add, delete, and update i18n messages
A cache for increased speed
A JSONP action which can be useful in client-side templating.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be flexible enough for the OP's case, with an existing database table that doesn't use standard message keys...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already have the database structure and want to mix with the messages.properties. In some cases I will use properties and others I will look in the database. I don't think that the plugin applies to that.