# Access i18n properties in production

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, properties-file

I am having an issue trying to access to some properties files in production but not in development mode.

This is the snippet I am using that is working in dev mode but in prod (tomcat):

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("grails-app/i18n/labels_${locale}.properties")
```

in which locale is a variable that I passed to return the proper content.

In production, the path is not right but I don't know how to access to this properties file in production. Any idea? Is this posible?

Comment: Why are you accessing the properties file like this? Just wondering, since there may be a better way to obtain them.

Comment: I need to get all the properties to add translation in a UI.

Comment: You are better off using a database for that information rather than modifying the property files on the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297505/grails-i18n-from-property-files-backed-up-by-a-db

Comment: There is even a good plugin with UI for this as well: https://github.com/goeh/grails-i18n-db

Comment: I have already the translations in the database, but I need to get the values of this properties that then will be overriden by the ones in the database.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Where are you calling this code from? What context? I ask because you will have to get a hold of the Grails environment.

Comment: I am calling this code from a service.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting `servletContext` in your service, then you should be able to get your file with:

```
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/labels_${locale}.properties")
```

Notice that in production `grails-app` folder is under `WEB-INF`