# Override Spring:message tag with database values

Tags: java, spring, properties, message

I am using Spring to display messages from a properties file.  I would like to be able to override the `<spring:message>` tag to use a value from a database based on the logged in user.  If this value is not present I would like it to default to the value currently in the properties file as it does now.

Can someone help me with this code?  I've read about AbstractMessageSource but I am unclear on how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to implement custom message source. It's a class that extends `AbstractMessageSource` and implements the abstract `resolveCode(java.lang.String, java.util.Locale)` method. There is almost [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100312/grails-i18n-from-database-but-default-back-to-file) on SO (it's solution for Grails), but I think it is good point to start from...

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a class called DatabaseMessageSource included below.  I still need to implement some kind of caching so I don't hit the database with each call.  This [link](http://graemerocher.blogspot.com/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html) was helpful too.  Thank you skaffman and PrimosK for pointing me in the right direction.

```
public class DatabaseMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;


    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {

        MyObj myObj = myDao.findByCode(code);

        MessageFormat format;

        if (myObj!= null && myObj.getId() != null) {

            format = new MessageFormat(myObj.getValue(), locale);

        } else {

            format = super.resolveCode(code, locale);

        }

        return format;

    }

    protected String resolveCodeWithoutArguments(String code, Locale locale) {

        MyObj myObj = myDao.findByCode(code);

        String format;

        if (myObj != null && myObj.getId() != null) {

            format = myObj.getValue();

        } else {

            format = super.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(code, locale);

        }

        return format;

    }

}
```

I updated my applicationContext to point to the newly created class.
I changed it to:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.mycompany.mypackage.DatabaseMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:defaultMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>    
</bean>`enter code here`
```

Comment: For caching I would suggest Ehcache... Take a look at [this](http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/thunderingherd) and [this](http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/spring-annotations)....

Comment: Thank you for this.  I will implement the first link.  You have been really helpful.  Thanks again

Comment: One follow up question.  How can I pass an object from the controller to my DatabaseMessageSource class?  The object is in session by the time the screen with the spring:message tags is loaded.

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean by passing an object to `DatabaseMessageSource`? Can you elaborate this? Or did you found solution already?

Comment: The screen that is using the messages is based on a logged in user.  So each user can have different customized messages.  Just wondering how I could pass this in so the DatabaseMessageSource knows which messages to get.

Comment: I think you don't have to pass anything... Take a look at `LocaleChangeInterceptor`... Maybe [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/) will help you...

Comment: Well I am doing a database look up based on the 'code' and a user id. I left the user id part out of my initial question. But my db call looks like MyObj myObj = myDao.find(code, id)

Comment: I think it would be better to post new question for this... I am sure you'll get the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the behaviour of `<spring:message>`, you just need to change the place it gets its messages from.

By default, it uses the `messageSource` bean in the context, which is of type `MessageSource`, or some subclass thereof. You can write your own class that implements `MessageSource` and add that to your context as the `messageSource` bean.

`AbstractMessageSource` is just a convenient starting point for writing your own `MessageSource`.  It does some of the work for you, just subclass it.