# Pass Session Variable to MessageSource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties, message

I have a controller that shows a form and loads messages from a properties file.  I extended `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and called it `DatabaseMessageSource`.  Now if there is a message in the database it will get that and if not default to what is in the proeprties file.  [Link to example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623388/override-springmessage-tag-with-database-values/10627332#comment13808290_10627332)

My database lookup is called like `getCode(companyId, code)`.  To make the above example work I just passed a `1` for `companyId`.

I would like to pass the companyId that is in session to the `DatabaseMessageSource` so it can pull the right messages for that particular company.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the current `HttpSession` at any point using this:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

Then get your attribute from there.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Worked perfect.