# How to customize LabelTag in springframework

Tags: java, jsp, tags, label, customization

**How to customize LabelTag?**
Any one can help me? 
I am using SpringMVC to cerate my java project, and now I have a problem, where I need to use LabelTag to show label text in JSP, these texts got from Database. For example:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    ....
    ....
    <body>
       <ab:form id="1" modelAttribute="loginForm" action="/login/login" >
            <tr>
                <td><spring:label path="userId" >UserID:</ab:label></td>
                <td>
                    <ab:input path="userId" required="true" fwformat="NONE" />
                    <ab:errors path="userId" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:label path="password" >PassWord:</ab:label></td>
                    <td>
                    <ab:password path="password" required="true" />
                    <ab:errors path="password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
     ....
     ....
```

In this JSP , I had set hardcoding-text for `UserID:` and `PassWord:`. But I need dinamically change these label text from Database according to the login user's location. For example , if user comes from America, they will show as **`UserID`** and **`PassWord`**, if user comes from Japan, i will shows **`ユーザID`** and **`パースワード`**, etc...

To achieve the upper goal, I am going to customize the LabelTag from Spring Framework. I pass the LabelTag the **text-ID** as pamareter, and the LabelTag will help me to get the correct Label text from Database accord to the **text-ID** parameter (The **text-ID** is set as a Primary Key in DB table), when JSP is rendered.

But I have no experience to customize LabelTag, How do I customize LabelTag to create a new LabelTag to achieve the goal?
Any one can help me ?  I'd appreciate you if you show the example src for me.

Comment: you'll need to use i18n properties resource bundles and something like`<spring:message code="string-key" text="default" />`

Comment: or if you want database-backed, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623388/override-springmessage-tag-with-database-values

Comment: @GUDO thank you for your quickly answer, and It is very helpful for me . I 'd refer them to implement it. Thanks . If any others have some advise, please let me know. Thanks very much.