# Grails async mail plugin with DatabaseMessageSource

Tags: email, grails, asynchronous, localization

In my Grails application, there is a requirement to allow different text to be shown to users on a per 'organisation' basis, but to fall back to reading the text from messages.properties if no overriding text is defined for an organisation.

I'm using an approach similar to the one detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100312/grails-i18n-from-database-but-default-back-to-file), which works well in the scope of an http request, however I now also need to define email content on a per organisation basis which is a bit problematic as emails are sent asynchronously (using the async mail plugin). My current `resolveCode()` implementation looks like this:

```
public MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
    Message msg = null
    try {
        Organisation currentOrganisation = currentOrganisationSessionProxy.currentSessionOrganisation
        msg = Message.findByCodeAndLocaleAndOrganisation(code, locale, currentOrganisation)
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        //handle exception
    }

    def format

    if (msg) {
        format = new MessageFormat(msg.text, msg.locale)
    } else {
        format = messageBundleMessageSource.resolveCode(code, locale)
    }

    return format
}
```

I've modified the DatabaseMessageSource implementation slightly as I need to resolve the current 'session' organisation using a session-scoped proxy.

Can anyone suggest a good approach for sending localized, organisation-specific emails asynchronously? I guess I would need to persist the organisation id along with the email, and then retrieve it some how in my `DatabaseMessageSource`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be simpler than I thought. I didn't need to modify the async mail plugin, but I did need to override the `ValidationTagLib` `g:message` implementation so that I could pass in an `organisationId`. I also needed to provide alternate implementations of `AbstractMessageSource.getMessage` methods that also took an `organisationId` argument.