# Grails - override message bundle property at runtime

Tags: grails

Is there a way to override at runtime the value of a property defined in a message bundle?

My grails application contains a property in the **messages.properties** file:

```
page1.para1.text=Some text to display to the user
```

My **Config.groovy** defines the following config location:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/.myApp/myApp-config.properties" ]
```

I currently use this approach to override Config.groovy properties (like db connections, etc), but it doesn't seen to apply to message bundle properties.

I was hoping/expecting to just make sure that the myApp-config.properties file contains my new property value, restart the Tomcat server where my app is deployed and it would get picked up and displayed on my page:

```
page1.para1.text=Some DIFFERENT text to display to the user
```

Grails docs on Internalization/Message bundles [grails i18n](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html) doesn't suggest if this is possible or not.

Obviously, I'm trying to achieve this change without the need to recompile and redeliver my Grails application.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the reason for this?

Comment: The usual reason: requirements have changed once we've gone live!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are already live and don't want to create a new .war file:

I'm not sure, but the .war file can be found unzipped on the server. You might try to replace the message files directly on the server, but a restart of the app might be necessary. But I wouldn't advice doing so.

If you need to often change the message bundles at runtime, I guess it would make sense to store them in the database. But that means that you have to change your code a little bit and redeploy it once. There is a blog entry which describes how to do it: http://graemerocher.blogspot.de/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html 
Another SO question handles the case that you want to store changes to the messages in a DB but fall back to the files: 
[Grails i18n From Database but Default Back To File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100312/grails-i18n-from-database-but-default-back-to-file)

hth

Comment: I've accepted this answer as in my scenario it was simple and easiest to change the messages.properties file in the unzipped Tomcat webapps folder and restart the server. I don't really have a requirement to implement the db solution, but thanks for the link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to replace the messageSource bean with a [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) inside Resources.groovy. This way you can not only point it to a new location but also declare how often they should be invalidated as cached values.