# Grails i18n localization dynamically from database

Tags: grails, internationalization

[Grails i18n From Database but Default Back To File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100312/grails-i18n-from-database-but-default-back-to-file)

The below code is implemented based on the above link.

```
 class DatabaseMessageSource extends PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource {
        Ehcache messageCache
        def messageBundleMessageSource

        @Override
        protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
            println code + " : " + locale.language
            def messageKey = new MessageKey(code, locale)
            def messageFormat = messageCache.get(messageKey)?.value

            if (!messageFormat) {
                I18nMessage i18nMessage = I18nMessage.findByCodeAndLanguageCode(code, locale.language)
                if (i18nMessage)
                    messageFormat = new MessageFormat(i18nMessage.text)
                else
                    messageFormat = super.resolveCode(code, locale)
                messageCache.put new Element(messageKey, messageFormat)
            }

            return messageFormat;
        }
```

In the resources.groovy file this bean is configured as 
shown in the below code.

```
beans = {
    messageCache(EhCacheFactoryBean) {
        timeToLive = 500
    }
    messageSource(DatabaseMessageSource) {
        messageCache = messageCache
        basename = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    }
}
```

In the gsp page g:message is called as shown below

```
1.<g:message code="someObject.create"/> 
2.<g:message code="someObject.create" default="Create"/>
3.<g:message code="someObject.create" args="['']"/>
```

For the same code given in the g:message tag, 1,2 is not displaying the text given in the database. The 3rd tag usage is showing the text content added in the database. 1 tag is showing the someObject.create. 2 Tag is showing Create value, 3rd tag shows the db text added.

why 1 and 2 notations are not displaying the dynamic value in the database? and also that the resolveCode() is called for 1Time only.

Comment: Have you tried turning on SQL logging to see what query is being issued for 1 and 2?

Comment: Before going to the sql level, the groovy method resolveCode() is not called for 1,2

Comment: Then it sounds like that tag library is using another method to resolve message codes. Poking around at the source I see this: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/72808948f70f3c9b00f55c16b9e52e4e1b0d3a67/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormatTagLib.groovy#L60